# Adding ToolTip (Description) to Vaadin ComboBox doesn't work, why?

Tags: combobox, tooltip, vaadin

I tried it with `cb.setDescription("text")` but it has no effect. So I searched the web but couldn't find anything about, why doesn't it work?

Here's the code:

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.setSizeUndefined();`
cb.setInputPrompt("xyz");
cb.addItem("x");
cb.addItem("y");
cb.setItemCaption("x", "xxx");
cb.setItemCaption("y", "yyy");
cb.setInvalidAllowed(false);
cb.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
cb.setNewItemsAllowed(false);
cb.setStyleName('xyz');
cb.select("x");
cb.setEnabled(false);
cb.setDescription("tooltiptext");
layout.addComponent(cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it connected with this [issue](http://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/3345). Right now it shown only on mouse over for cobmobox button, but not textfield.

Answer (score 0):

I dont belive you can have it `setEditable(false)` and get a caption so try with `setEnabled(true)` and also use `setImmediate(true)`